# How to find contours in an image with some sequence using opencv

Tags: image-processing, opencv, contour

I got the no of contours of this image using function of cvFindcontour its fine and also i got the each contour using to increment contour->h_next.

```
cvFindContours( src, storage, &contour, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
```

but sequence of the contour was random,is there any way to find the contour as such given format in the image? my ultimate aim was to find the area of outer squares alone(i.e)(1,2,3,4,9,10,15,16,17,18 alone).please can you suggest some algorithm or function to find the contour with this sequence.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest :

- find the center of masses of each square
- find the orientation of the checkboard by a fit or a hough transform
- perform rotation of the center of mass coordinates
- sort squares according to new coordinates

Comment: Thanks for your reply...is there any direct function in opencv to sort this square...

Comment: I don't think so. At this point a simple C/C++ function should sort this out.

Comment: You can perform a Hough transform on the image of contours. It will generate an image which high values corresponding to most probable orientation of the checkboard.